# Grouping hierarchical data with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a search view that needs to return a grouping of all employees based on their level in the organization hierarchy.  The user needs to have the  ability to group by any level in this hierarchy.  So for example, I have drop down check lists that allow 1 or more options to be selected for Division, Department, Section, Group.

The way that I have the organization structure represented in my data model is like this:

```
public class OrganizationEntity : IEntity
{

    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int OrganizationEntityTypeId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ForeignKey("OrganizationEntityTypeId")]
    public virtual OrganizationEntityType OrganizationEntityType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual OrganizationEntity Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationEntity> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The OrganizationEntityType tells me where in the organization hierarchy I am.

Employees are only linked to one organization entity so employee model looks like:

```
public class Employee : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]        
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int CityId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ForeignKey("CityId")]
    public virtual City City { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int OrganizationEntityId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ForeignKey("OrganizationEntityId")]
    public virtual OrganizationEntity OrganizationEntity { get; set; }

}
```

Now I'm trying to figure out the best way to group by a level in the org hierarchy using LINQ.  So say the user selects Division 1, Division 2, All Sections, Group 1 and has their grouping set to Divisions I would need to see the data looks something like this:

Divisions       Employee Count
division1               25
division2               3

And if the same parameters where the same except the grouping was set to Section the data would look like:

Sections       Employee Count
Section1            15
Section2             3
Section3             4

And so on for the other levels.

Here is a sample dataset:

[image]

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

### Update

Added a filter to the employees query to only include those in the Org level being group by and all of those below it and now works great!  Code looks like this:

```
var employees = context.Employees.Where(o => orgEntityIds.Contains(o.OrganizationEntityId));
```

Comment: LINQ is not at its best with hierarchical data. Simple `foreach` will do the job. Or create a database view wrapping a hierarchical query (using a CTE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ can do this with the `GroupBy` method, but you'll have to be a bit creative with the way you generate the grouping key.  Here's a rough idea:

```
Func<Employee, string> selector = (n => FindOrganizationName(n.OrganizationEntity, orgType));
Dictionary<string, int> results = employees.GroupBy(selector)
                                           .ToDictionary(n => n.Key, n => n.Count());
```

where `FindOrganizationName` is a recursive function that crawls up the organization hierarchy until it finds the requested organization type, like this:

```
string FindOrganizationName(OrganizationEntity entity, int entityType)
{
    if (entity == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    else if (entity.OrganizationEntityTypeId == entityType)
    {
        return entity.Name;
    }
    else
    {
        return FindOrganizationName(entity.Parent, entityType);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working great for the top level grouping "Divisions" but when I try and group any lower I'm getting error: Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: key

Comment: That suggests that there is an `Employee` in your list that is not part of the organization type you're looking for.  If that is by design, you should modify the `if (entity == null) portion of `FindOrganizationName` so that it returns a "real" string instead of null.  Then you can filter out the result with that string as a key.

Comment: I've updated my question with the sample data that I'm using.  All employees have an organizationEntity associated with them.

Comment: Even if all the employees have an organization entity association, it's possible that they might not have the right *type* of organization.  For example, if you're searching based on Section (where each Section is associated with a Division) but some employees are associated directly to a Division, then those employees aren't associated with a Section.

Comment: Updated my question to contain the query that fixed my issue.  Thanks so much for your help!  Really appreciate it :-)